# Four Numbers Program: Grouping numbers

Tags: java

I created a program that enables you to type in four numbers that must have specific requirements:
-must be a multiple of 4 or 6
-if greater than 500, must be a multiple of 10

The program takes the four numbers and gives you the sum of them, the average of them, shows you the smallest of the four numbers and finally the largest of the four numbers.

Now I want to try and display a group that each number belong to. I want these groups if you were wondering:
Group Tens if the number is between 0 and 99
Group Hundreds if the number is between 100 and 999
Group Thousands if the number is between 1000 and 999,999
Group Others if the number is greater than 999,999

My problem is I do not know where I should being placing them into my program (below)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FourNumbersProgram {

private static int readNumber(String message, Scanner in) {
    System.out.println("Enter a numbers divislbe by 4 or 6. No negatives.");
    System.out.println("**If greater than 500: must be multiple of 10");
    System.out.print(message);
    while (!in.hasNextInt()) {
        in.next();
        System.out.println("Sorry, couldn't understand you!");
        System.out.print(message);
    }
    int a = in.nextInt();
    return a;
}

private static int readNumberToMatchCondition(String message, Scanner in) {
    int number = 0;
    do {
        number = readNumber(message, in);
        if (number < 500) {
            if (number % 4 != 0 && number % 6 != 0) {
                System.out.println(number + " not divisible by 4 or 6");
            } else {
                return number;
            }
        } else {
            if (number % 4 != 0 && number % 6 != 0) {
                System.out.println(number + " not divisible by 4 or 6");
            } else if (number % 10 != 0) {
                System.out.println(number + " is greater than 500 and not divisible by 10");
            } else {
                return number;
            }

        }
    } while (true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    int randomNumber1 = readNumberToMatchCondition("Enter first number:", in);
    int randomNumber2 = readNumberToMatchCondition("Enter second number:", in);
    int randomNumber3 = readNumberToMatchCondition("Enter third number:", in);
    int randomNumber4 = readNumberToMatchCondition("Enter fourth number:", in);


    int sum; // sum of number1, number2, number3, and number4
    int avg; // average of number1, number2, number3, and number4
    int largest; // largest number of the four integers
    int smallest; // smallest number of the four integers

    sum = (randomNumber1 + randomNumber2 + randomNumber3 + randomNumber4);

    avg = ((sum) / 4);

      smallest = randomNumber1;
        smallest = (randomNumber2 < smallest) ? randomNumber2 : smallest;
        smallest = (randomNumber3 < smallest) ? randomNumber3 : smallest;
        smallest = (randomNumber4 < smallest) ? randomNumber3 : smallest;


      largest = randomNumber1;
        largest = (randomNumber2 > largest) ? randomNumber2 :largest;
        largest = (randomNumber3 > largest) ? randomNumber3 :largest;
        largest = (randomNumber4 > largest) ? randomNumber4 :largest;

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("First number entered: " + randomNumber1); //prints first number entered
    System.out.println("Second number entered: " + randomNumber2); //prints second number entered
    System.out.println("Third number entered: " + randomNumber3); //prints third number entered
    System.out.println("Fourth number entered: " + randomNumber4); //prints fourth number entered
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("The sum is: " + sum); //prints sum of four numbers
    System.out.println("The average is: " + avg); //prints average of four numbers
    System.out.println("The smallest number is:  " + smallest); //prints smallest of the four numbers
    System.out.println("The largest number is:  " + largest); //prints largest of the four numbers
    System.out.println();
}
}
```

Here is a transcript of my code:
[image]



my professor gave me this sample of a grouping program (below)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Prog2 {

  public static void main(String[] args){

       Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);// read a number

       System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
       int number = in.nextInt();

       if (number < 0) {
            System.out.println("Error: Sorry, no negative numbers allowed.");

            System.exit(0);
       }


       int grp1 = (number / 100) + 1;
       int grp2 = (number / 1000) + 1;
       int grp3 = (number / 1000000) + 1;

       switch (grp1){
       case 1: // Group Tens
            System.out.println(number + " belongs to Group Tens");

            break;
       default:
            switch (grp2) {
            case 1:// Group Hundreds
                 System.out.println(number + " belongs to Group Hundreds");

                 break;
            default:
                 switch (grp3) {
                 case 1:// Group Thousands
                      System.out.println(number + " belongs to Group Thousands");

                      break;
                 default:// Group Others
                      System.out.println(number + " belongs to Group Others");
}

}

}

in.close();
}

}
```

Heres a transcript of his code:
[image]



I know his program is asking for the user to type in **one** number and the program groups it. I was wondering how to put something like this into my program. I am confused because I have four numbers that have to be grouped and I'm not sure if I have to repeat something similar to my professors program for all of my four numbers (randomNumber1, randomNumber2, randomNumber3, randomNumber4

 Please no positing an entire corrected code! I want to fix it myself and learn!

Comment: after seeing your professor's code, i think he shouldn't teach somebody java/algorithms/coding or whatever he teaches

Comment: i sadly agree with you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your professors program will work for all of your numbers. All you need to do is call the method 4 times. Once for each number. What you need to do is put his code into a method on it's own. (Remember, if he's given it to you as a guide, then he will probably want you to give a go at writing the logic yourself).

Let's say you put his code in a method that looks like:

```
public void displayNumberGroup(int number)
{
   // Displays number group using your prof's code.
}
```

Then, next, all you need to do is pass each value that you've loaded, into that method. For example: `displayNumberGroup(randomNumber1);`. This will calculate the grouping for that number. I'll leave it up to you to put this stuff into context, since you've requested to not be spoonfed the answer (which is very commendable!).

Comment: sorry but I am not understand when you say "all you need to do is call the method four times" when you mean the method do you mean the method I will be putting my professors code in??

Comment: That is correct. Put your professor's code into a method, and call that method with each of the four numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing randomNumber1, randomNumber2, ect you can make them into an array. By doing that, you can then put a for loop over the given switch and run it 4 times so all of your numbers have groups. If you need me to explain any part of this with a simple example I will, but I know you want to do most of this yourself so if you have any questions let me know.